# lspci shows wifi adapter but network manager finds nothing (iwlwifi error -22?)

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, iwlwifi

Trying to get my PC to connect to wifi; network manager is not showing any wifi connections.

```
hostnamectl
...
    Operating System: EndeavourOS                     
          Kernel: Linux 5.18.2-arch1-1
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: System manufacturer
  Hardware Model: System Product Name
Firmware Version: 2606
```

LSPCI finds an AX200:

```
lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

iwconfig doesn't find anything wireless: (I think one of the ones it does show is  a 4g modem currently plugged in over USB, which is the only way I'm currently able to connect)

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp6s0f1u1  no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.
```

This might be helpful? :

```
 lspci -k | grep -i network -A 2
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
--
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 85f0
    Kernel driver in use: igb
```

Wondering if maybe iwlwifi is the culprit? From what I can gather I should see "Kernel driver in use" but I don't, and I'm not sure what to do about that.

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    4.984914] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.988489] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Can find a correct rfid for crf id 0x5a2
[    4.988501] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -22
```

But at that point I'm not sure if I've wandered into the weeds and I'm not finding anything useful.

Comment: Please try kernel 5.18.2.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Upgraded, no change

Comment: Do you have Windows installed? Can you confirm it's working there? If it does, please file a bug report at bugzilla.kernel.org

Comment: Most Intel PCIe WiFi adapters need firmware. What do you get if you run `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`? If there are messages about failing to load a particular firmware file, you should check that the firmware file is present in `/lib/firmware/`, and if not, download it from the [linux-firmware repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov No Windows, no. It was working once upon a time under a different linux distro though, but that was a while ago - I can't even remember the distro.

Comment: @telcoM the output of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` is already in my OP - it contains `failed with error -22` which I haven't been able to figure out what is.

Comment: It could be dead. You can try running a live Windows edition and see if it works, or install Windows Enterprise Eval temporarily.